# why do we use a call list with retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have an example ,I want to understand some parts,In this exampl ,It was working fine ,but when I changed part 
from:
`call list<model>> method();`
to:
`call <model> method();`

It caused an error ,What's the reason for that? 
What is the difference between the two cases?

```
// MainActivity :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            GetData service = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetData.class);

            Call<RetroUsers> call = service.getAllUsers();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<RetroUsers>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RetroUsers> call, Response<RetroUsers> response) {
                    Log.i("print", "" + response.body().getUser());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RetroUsers> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("print", "Dont" + t.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }



    ///Error message :
    I/print: Dontjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $


    // interface GetData:
    public interface GetData {
        @GET("/users")
        Call<RetroUsers>getAllUsers();
        /*
        @GET("/users")
        Call<List<RetroUsers>> getAllUsers();
        */
    }

    // RetrofitClient :
    public class RetrofitClient {

        private static Retrofit retrofit;
        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";


        public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
    }



       // model class :

        public class RetroUsers {

            @SerializedName("name")
            private String name;


            public RetroUsers(String name) {
                this.name = name;

            }

            public String getUser() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setUser(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }



        }
```

Comment: Well, the exception already tells you what the problem is: you changed the return type in the interface from a list to a single object, but the implementation still sends a list. Thus "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" which means the client expected an object starting with `{` but got an array/list, starting with `[`. - Note that you can't just change the interface of a webservice on the client, the service itself would have to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `Call<RetroUsers> getAllUsers();`

will cause you an error because the getAllUsers() will return more than one records of RetroUsers. Due to which it requires you to provide it a type as List so that its datatype is set to List and it can then handle multiple records.

Go through basics of Core Java to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In one case you tell the deserializer that you expect *a single* `Model`, in the other case you tell it to expect a list of models, aka a `List<Model>`. Depending on what data you actually get you need to use one or the oter.
Of course you can "hide" the List<...> within your model by not using `List<Model>` but:

```
public class MoreThanOneModel {
    public List<Model> entries;
    ...
}
```

But that does not change the underlying reasoning.